# Why is the byte[] different when serializing with protocol buffers for java and protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, java, protocol-buffers, zeromq, protobuf-net

When I serialize this object with protocol buffers in Java, I get this byte array:

```
byte[] topic = Transport.newBuilder()
            .setTopic(Topics.ORD)
            .setExtension(Ord.command, Commands.INSERT)
            .build()
            .toByteArray();

// [8,2,16,0]
```

When I do the same with protobuf-net, I get this

```
var transport = new Transport
{
    topic = Topics.ORD,
    command = Commands.INSERT
};

var stream = new MemoryStream();
Serializer.Serialize(stream, transport);
byte[] result = stream.ToArray(); // [8,2]
```

This causes me some trouble when using zmq and a subscription based on the bye array.
How can i make sure that both arrays will look the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

protobuf-net, in v1, made a "zero defaults" assumption. Probably not a decision I would make again, if I was starting from scratch, and indeed this behaviour can be disabled in v2. But as it stands, in many cases it assumes zero as an implicit default. I'm guessing that your `command` is a non-nullable enum, in which case it will apply this logic (as a side-note: if it was *nullable*, it would *not* do this - it would use the `null` check for the include/exclude decision).

Because of this, it has decided that the second field (field number 2, encoded as varint) doesn't need to be serialized. Hence no `[16, 0]`.

Options:

- use a *nullable* member (equivalent to `optional`) - i.e. `public SomeEnum? Command {get;set;}`
- mark the member as *required* (`IsRequired=true` on the `ProtoMemberAttribute`)
- turn off implicit zero default behaviour (`UseImplicitZeroDefaults` on a `RuntimeTypeModel` instance)

Comment: Okay, I have set the field in the proto file to required. Now I get `[8,2,176,6,0]` in c# and `[8,2,-80,6,0]` in Java

Comment: @mrt181 that's just because java has signed bytes and C# has unsigned bytes; 176 and -80 are the same thing (binary 10110000)